# Speedup INSERT SELECT query on heavy data using PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to insert data by **INSERT SELECT** query. It takes more than 40 seconds to INSERT data. Table `purchase_order` has >8000 records. How can I INSERT data with high speed with following query?

**PHP variables:** `$invoID=round(microtime(true)*1000);,$image= "n/a";,$salePrice=100;,$status="Avbl";,$cid=1;,$uid=1;,$pid=see heading and $ttlQinTempSale=may 1,5,89 or of your choice.`

```
mysqli_query($con," INSERT INTO `temp_sale`
    (    SELECT
            null,
            '$invoID',
            '$image',
            x.pid,
            x.product_code,
            x.product_name,
            x.pack_size,
            x.batch_number,
            x.expiry_date,
            x.qty_avbl,
            0.00,
            x.pur_price,
            '$salePrice',
            '$status',
            now(),
            '$cid',
            '$uid',
    GREATEST(SUM(y.qty_avbl)- $ttlQinTempSale ,0) AS balance
             FROM purchase_order AS x
             JOIN purchase_order AS y
               ON y.pid = x.pid
              AND y.batch_number <= x.batch_number
         GROUP BY x.tid
           HAVING balance < qty_avbl
              AND pid = $pid
         ORDER BY batch_number ASC
    )
            ");
```

** Format for table "temp_sale" **

```
CREATE TABLE `temp_sale` (
  `tid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `invoice` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `pro_image` varchar(100) DEFAULT 'images/',
  `product` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `product_code` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `product_name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `pack_size` int(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `batch_number` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `expiry_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `qty` int(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `prcntge` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `pur_price` decimal(10,5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00000',
  `price` decimal(10,5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00000',
  `status` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'USER',
  `timeStamp` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `cid` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `uid` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `balance` int(6) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

** Format for table "purchase_order" This is just sample data. Original records in this table are >8000 **

```
CREATE TABLE `purchase_order` (
  `tid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `invoice` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `pid` int(6) NOT NULL,
  `category` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `product_code` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `product_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `batch_number` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `batch_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `expiry_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `salePrice` decimal(13,5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00000',
  `pur_price` decimal(13,5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00000',
  `discount` decimal(13,5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00000',
  `ttl_disc` decimal(13,5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00000',
  `unitPrice` decimal(13,5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00000',
  `grossPrice` decimal(13,5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00000',
  `opnBal` int(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `pack_size` int(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `packs` int(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `loose` int(5) DEFAULT '0',
  `bonus` int(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `qty` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `clzBal` int(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `qty_sold` int(6) DEFAULT '0',
  `qty_avbl` int(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `dis_type` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `dateTime` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `purchase_order` (`tid`, `invoice`, `pid`, `category`, `product_code`, `product_name`, `batch_number`, `batch_date`, `expiry_date`, `salePrice`, `pur_price`, `discount`, `ttl_disc`, `unitPrice`, `grossPrice`, `opnBal`, `pack_size`, `packs`, `loose`, `bonus`, `qty`, `clzBal`, `qty_sold`, `qty_avbl`, `dis_type`, `dateTime`) VALUES
(1, '228367', 1, 'Tooth Paste', '8992695714060', 'SENSODYNE GUM CARE', '1706167082339', '2021-09-20', '2021-09-20', '140.00000', '105.00000', '0.00000', '0.00000', '105.00000', '105000.00000', 0, 1, 1000, 0, 0, 1000, 1000, 4, 3, 'disco_percent', '2021-09-14 05:22:22'),
(2, '881279', 2, 'Biscuit', 'B280', 'BISCUIT', '1708379591233', '2021-09-20', '2021-09-20', '280.00000', '280.00000', '0.00000', '0.00000', '280.00000', '280000.00000', 0, 1, 1000, 0, 0, 1000, 1000, 0, 1000, 'disco_percent', '2021-09-14 05:22:22'),
(3, '145958', 3, 'Biscuit', '8964000681077', 'Sooper Biscuits', '90063478261', '2021-09-20', '2021-09-20', '10.00000', '10.00000', '0.00000', '0.00000', '10.00000', '10000.00000', 0, 1, 1000, 0, 0, 1000, 1000, 5, 995, 'disco_percent', '2021-09-14 05:22:22'),
(4, '755030', 4, 'Biscuit', '8964000681084', 'Sooper Biscuits', '1991845386716', '2021-09-20', '2021-09-20', '115.00000', '115.00000', '0.00000', '0.00000', '115.00000', '115000.00000', 0, 1, 1000, 0, 0, 1000, 1000, 0, 1000, 'disco_percent', '2021-09-14 05:22:22'),
(5, '761943', 5, 'Biscuit', '8961003020315', 'Candi Biscuits', '3022369934577', '2021-09-20', '2021-09-20', '22.00000', '20.00000', '0.00000', '0.00000', '20.00000', '20000.00000', 0, 1, 1000, 0, 0, 1000, 1000, 0, 1000, 'disco_percent', '2021-09-14 05:22:22'),
(6, '700321', 6, 'Biscuit', '8961003046018', 'Oreo Biscuits', '2469646948517', '2021-09-20', '2021-09-20', '10.00000', '10.00000', '0.00000', '0.00000', '10.00000', '10000.00000', 0, 1, 1000, 0, 0, 1000, 1000, 0, 1000, 'disco_percent', '2021-09-14 05:22:22'),
(7, '397499', 7, 'Biscuit', '8961003653001', 'Oreo Biscuits tikky', '3281125041297', '2021-09-20', '2021-09-20', '5.00000', '5.00000', '0.00000', '0.00000', '5.00000', '5000.00000', 0, 1, 1000, 0, 0, 1000, 1000, 0, 1000, 'disco_percent', '2021-09-14 05:22:22'),
(8, '779038', 8, 'Biscuit', '8961003021749', 'Butter Biscuits', '2330017796715', '2021-09-20', '2021-09-20', '22.00000', '20.00000', '0.00000', '0.00000', '20.00000', '20000.00000', 0, 1, 1000, 0, 0, 1000, 1000, 0, 1000, 'disco_percent', '2021-09-14 05:22:22'),
(9, '377540', 9, 'Biscuit', '8964000682050', 'Gluco Biscuits', '1806713962127', '2021-09-20', '2021-09-20', '10.00000', '10.00000', '0.00000', '0.00000', '10.00000', '10000.00000', 0, 1, 1000, 0, 0, 1000, 1000, 0, 1000, 'disco_percent', '2021-09-14 05:22:22'),
(10, '712793', 10, 'Biscuit', '8961003024016', 'Bistiks Biscuits', '2043516522935', '2021-09-20', '2021-09-20', '22.00000', '20.00000', '0.00000', '0.00000', '20.00000', '20000.00000', 0, 1, 1000, 0, 0, 1000, 1000, 0, 1000, 'disco_percent', '2021-09-14 05:22:22'),
(11, '100420', 11, 'Biscuit', '8964001526124', 'Badaam Biscuits', '1464107497407', '2021-09-20', '2021-09-20', '10.00000', '10.00000', '0.00000', '0.00000', '10.00000', '10000.00000', 0, 1, 1000, 0, 0, 1000, 1000, 0, 1000, 'disco_percent', '2021-09-14 05:22:22'),
(12, '788387', 12, 'Biscuit', '8961003020520', 'Gala Biscuits', '1189988020674', '2021-09-20', '2021-09-20', '22.00000', '20.00000', '0.00000', '0.00000', '20.00000', '20000.00000', 0, 1, 1000, 0, 0, 1000, 1000, 0, 1000, 'disco_percent', '2021-09-14 05:22:22'),
(13, '46555', 13, 'Biscuit', '8961003026010', 'Oreo Biscuits', '1557617713596', '2021-09-20', '2021-09-20', '22.00000', '20.00000', '0.00000', '0.00000', '20.00000', '20000.00000', 0, 1, 1000, 0, 0, 1000, 1000, 0, 1000, 'disco_percent', '2021-09-14 05:22:22'),
(14, '42832', 14, 'Biscuit', '8961003030215', 'Tuc Biscuits', '884791275069', '2021-09-20', '2021-09-20', '130.00000', '120.00000', '0.00000', '0.00000', '120.00000', '120000.00000', 0, 1, 1000, 0, 0, 1000, 1000, 0, 1000, 'disco_percent', '2021-09-14 05:22:22'),
(15, '492655', 15, 'Biscuit', '671866128988', 'Bravo Biscuits', '3084436670335', '2021-09-20', '2021-09-20', '10.00000', '10.00000', '0.00000', '0.00000', '10.00000', '10000.00000', 0, 1, 1000, 0, 0, 1000, 1000, 0, 1000, 'disco_percent', '2021-09-14 05:22:22'),
(16, '747167', 16, 'Biscuit', '8961003034015', 'Biscuits', '2767809628914', '2021-09-20', '2021-09-20', '130.00000', '120.00000', '0.00000', '0.00000', '120.00000', '120000.00000', 0, 1, 1000, 0, 0, 1000, 1000, 0, 1000, 'disco_percent', '2021-09-14 05:22:22'),
(17, '163384', 17, 'Biscuit', '8964001188735', 'Jolly Jam Biscuit', '1252404902676', '2021-09-20', '2021-09-20', '115.00000', '115.00000', '0.00000', '0.00000', '115.00000', '115000.00000', 0, 1, 1000, 0, 0, 1000, 1000, 0, 1000, 'disco_percent', '2021-09-14 05:22:22'),
(18, '744130', 18, 'Biscuit', '8964001188353', 'Jolly Jam Biscuit', '1291929062418', '2021-09-20', '2021-09-20', '115.00000', '115.00000', '0.00000', '0.00000', '115.00000', '115000.00000', 0, 1, 1000, 0, 0, 1000, 1000, 0, 1000, 'disco_percent', '2021-09-14 05:22:22'),
(19, '149025', 19, 'Biscuit', '8961003513213', 'Prince Chocolate Biscuit', '2702430706505', '2021-09-20', '2021-09-20', '115.00000', '115.00000', '0.00000', '0.00000', '115.00000', '115000.00000', 0, 1, 1000, 0, 0, 1000, 1000, 0, 1000, 'disco_percent', '2021-09-14 05:22:22'),
(20, '918618', 20, 'Biscuit', '8964002487271', 'Chip Choc Biscuit', '2969699781050', '2021-09-20', '2021-09-20', '5.00000', '5.00000', '0.00000', '0.00000', '5.00000', '5000.00000', 0, 1, 1000, 0, 0, 1000, 1000, 0, 1000, 'disco_percent', '2021-09-14 05:22:22'),
(21, '570680', 21, 'Biscuit', '8964002526468', 'CHOCO LICIOUS Biscuit', '74540221513', '2021-09-20', '2021-09-20', '115.00000', '100.00000', '0.00000', '0.00000', '100.00000', '100000.00000', 0, 1, 1000, 0, 0, 1000, 1000, 0, 1000, 'disco_percent', '2021-09-14 05:22:22'),
(22, '272761', 22, 'Biscuit', '8964000685617', 'Choco Licious Biscuit', '1463601866859', '2021-09-20', '2021-09-20', '5.00000', '5.00000', '0.00000', '0.00000', '5.00000', '5000.00000', 0, 1, 1000, 0, 0, 1000, 1000, 0, 1000, 'disco_percent', '2021-09-14 05:22:22'),
(23, '813971', 23, 'Biscuit', '8964002526994', 'JAM DELIGHT Biscuit', '427722105534', '2021-09-20', '2021-09-20', '10.00000', '8.00000', '0.00000', '0.00000', '8.00000', '8000.00000', 0, 1, 1000, 0, 0, 1000, 1000, 0, 1000, 'disco_percent', '2021-09-14 05:22:22'),
(24, '650948', 24, 'Biscuit', '8964002528073', 'SOOPER Biscuit', '1081138362874', '2021-09-20', '2021-09-20', '20.00000', '20.00000', '0.00000', '0.00000', '20.00000', '20000.00000', 0, 1, 1000, 0, 0, 1000, 1000, 0, 1000, 'disco_percent', '2021-09-14 05:22:22'),
(25, '737859', 25, 'Biscuit', '8961003654176', 'OREO Biscuit', '789192266877', '2021-09-20', '2021-09-20', '10.00000', '10.00000', '0.00000', '0.00000', '10.00000', '10000.00000', 0, 1, 1000, 0, 0, 1000, 1000, 0, 1000, 'disco_percent', '2021-09-14 05:22:22'),
(26, '654976', 26, 'Biscuit', '8961003553165', 'OREO Biscuit', '702546348208', '2021-09-20', '2021-09-20', '115.00000', '115.00000', '0.00000', '0.00000', '115.00000', '115000.00000', 0, 1, 1000, 0, 0, 1000, 1000, 0, 1000, 'disco_percent', '2021-09-14 05:22:22'),
(27, '716638', 27, 'Biscuit', '870572001404', 'Rite Biscuit', '1145155042856', '2021-09-20', '2021-09-20', '5.00000', '5.00000', '0.00000', '0.00000', '5.00000', '5000.00000', 0, 1, 1000, 0, 0, 1000, 1000, 0, 1000, 'disco_percent', '2021-09-14 05:22:22'),
(28, '293844', 28, 'Biscuit', '8964002526963', 'JAM DELIGHT Biscuit', '284802938767', '2021-09-20', '2021-09-20', '20.00000', '19.00000', '0.00000', '0.00000', '19.00000', '19000.00000', 0, 1, 1000, 0, 0, 1000, 1000, 0, 1000, 'disco_percent', '2021-09-14 05:22:22'),
(29, '994156', 29, 'Biscuit', '8961003021787', 'Bakeri Butter Biscuit', '1321883001044', '2021-09-20', '2021-09-20', '10.00000', '9.00000', '0.00000', '0.00000', '9.00000', '9000.00000', 0, 1, 1000, 0, 0, 1000, 1000, 0, 1000, 'disco_percent', '2021-09-14 05:22:22'),
(30, '488622', 30, 'Biscuit', '8964002526598', 'PARTY Biscuit', '2421672958032', '2021-09-20', '2021-09-20', '115.00000', '115.00000', '0.00000', '0.00000', '115.00000', '115000.00000', 0, 1, 1000, 0, 0, 1000, 1000, 0, 1000, 'disco_percent', '2021-09-14 05:22:22'),
(31, '141996', 31, 'Biscuit', '8964002526604', 'PARTI Biscuit', '1476049222806', '2021-09-20', '2021-09-20', '115.00000', '100.00000', '0.00000', '0.00000', '100.00000', '100000.00000', 0, 1, 1000, 0, 0, 1000, 1000, 0, 1000, 'disco_percent', '2021-09-14 05:22:22'),
(32, '412825', 32, 'Biscuit', '8964002526345', 'BUTTERPUFF Biscuit', '115227342381', '2021-09-20', '2021-09-20', '115.00000', '100.00000', '0.00000', '0.00000', '100.00000', '100000.00000', 0, 1, 1000, 0, 0, 1000, 1000, 0, 1000, 'disco_percent', '2021-09-14 05:22:22'),
(33, '293468', 33, 'Biscuit', '8964002526239', 'BUTTR PUFF Biscuit', '2814655812595', '2021-09-20', '2021-09-20', '115.00000', '115.00000', '0.00000', '0.00000', '115.00000', '115000.00000', 0, 1, 1000, 0, 0, 1000, 1000, 0, 1000, 'disco_percent', '2021-09-14 05:22:22'),
(34, '884931', 34, 'Biscuit', '8961003583032', 'WHEAT Biscuit', '394263804947', '2021-09-20', '2021-09-20', '115.00000', '115.00000', '0.00000', '0.00000', '115.00000', '115000.00000', 0, 1, 1000, 0, 0, 1000, 1000, 0, 1000, 'disco_percent', '2021-09-14 05:22:22'),
(35, '968917', 35, 'Biscuit', '8964002528790', 'MARI Biscuit', '194018356062', '2021-09-20', '2021-09-20', '115.00000', '100.00000', '0.00000', '0.00000', '100.00000', '100000.00000', 0, 1, 1000, 0, 0, 1000, 1000, 0, 1000, 'disco_percent', '2021-09-14 05:22:22'),
(36, '351997', 36, 'Biscuit', '8964002527021', 'JAM DELIGHT Biscuit', '3120633801247', '2021-09-20', '2021-09-20', '20.00000', '18.00000', '0.00000', '0.00000', '18.00000', '18000.00000', 0, 1, 1000, 0, 0, 1000, 1000, 0, 1000, 'disco_percent', '2021-09-14 05:22:22'),
(37, '515803', 37, 'Biscuit', '8964002528509', 'Gulco Biscuit', '1687780707163', '2021-09-20', '2021-09-20', '5.00000', '5.00000', '0.00000', '0.00000', '5.00000', '5000.00000', 0, 1, 1000, 0, 0, 1000, 1000, 0, 1000, 'disco_percent', '2021-09-14 05:22:22'),
(38, '934681', 38, 'Biscuit', '8964001434696', 'mighty Biscuit', '2410335567852', '2021-09-20', '2021-09-20', '115.00000', '100.00000', '0.00000', '0.00000', '100.00000', '100000.00000', 0, 1, 1000, 0, 0, 1000, 1000, 0, 1000, 'disco_percent', '2021-09-14 05:22:22'),
(39, '538381', 39, 'Biscuit', '8964000683057', 'Lemon Biscuit', '321669153548', '2021-09-20', '2021-09-20', '115.00000', '115.00000', '0.00000', '0.00000', '115.00000', '115000.00000', 0, 1, 1000, 0, 0, 1000, 1000, 0, 1000, 'disco_percent', '2021-09-14 05:22:22'),
(40, '69586', 40, 'Biscuit', '8964002528974', 'LEMON Biscuit', '1044005833297', '2021-09-20', '2021-09-20', '20.00000', '18.00000', '0.00000', '0.00000', '18.00000', '18000.00000', 0, 1, 1000, 0, 0, 1000, 1000, 0, 1000, 'disco_percent', '2021-09-14 05:22:22'),
(41, '881981', 41, 'Biscuit', '8964002528998', 'LEMON Biscuit', '921688474953', '2021-09-20', '2021-09-20', '115.00000', '100.00000', '0.00000', '0.00000', '100.00000', '100000.00000', 0, 1, 1000, 0, 0, 1000, 1000, 0, 1000, 'disco_percent', '2021-09-14 05:22:22'),
(42, '633049', 42, 'Biscuit', '8964000683040', 'Lemon Biscuit', '1476424977317', '2021-09-20', '2021-09-20', '5.00000', '5.00000', '0.00000', '0.00000', '5.00000', '5000.00000', 0, 1, 1000, 0, 0, 1000, 1000, 0, 1000, 'disco_percent', '2021-09-14 05:22:22'),
(43, '924452', 43, 'Biscuit', '8964000682814', 'MARIE Biscuit', '1283726230839', '2021-09-20', '2021-09-20', '10.00000', '10.00000', '0.00000', '0.00000', '10.00000', '10000.00000', 0, 1, 1000, 0, 0, 1000, 1000, 0, 1000, 'disco_percent', '2021-09-14 05:22:22'),
(44, '397962', 44, 'Biscuit', '8961003036019', 'Oreo Biscuit', '1989356324688', '2021-09-20', '2021-09-20', '130.00000', '120.00000', '0.00000', '0.00000', '120.00000', '120000.00000', 0, 1, 1000, 0, 0, 1000, 1000, 0, 1000, 'disco_percent', '2021-09-14 05:22:22'),
(45, '872520', 45, 'Biscuit', '8961003031038', 'Zeera Plus Biscuit', '2762269700035', '2021-09-20', '2021-09-20', '115.00000', '115.00000', '0.00000', '0.00000', '115.00000', '115000.00000', 0, 1, 1000, 0, 0, 1000, 1000, 0, 1000, 'disco_percent', '2021-09-14 05:22:22'),
(46, '350435', 46, 'Biscuit', '8964001434429', 'Zeera Biscuit', '1176612961892', '2021-09-20', '2021-09-20', '15.00000', '15.00000', '0.00000', '0.00000', '15.00000', '15000.00000', 0, 1, 1000, 0, 0, 1000, 1000, 0, 1000, 'disco_percent', '2021-09-14 05:22:22'),
(47, '33626', 47, 'Biscuit', '8964001188971', 'Zeera Kalonji Biscuit', '929589145131', '2021-09-20', '2021-09-20', '115.00000', '115.00000', '0.00000', '0.00000', '115.00000', '115000.00000', 0, 1, 1000, 0, 0, 1000, 1000, 0, 1000, 'disco_percent', '2021-09-14 05:22:22'),
(48, '529211', 48, 'Biscuit', '8961003030345', 'Candi Biscuit', '1118106942424', '2021-09-20', '2021-09-20', '130.00000', '120.00000', '0.00000', '0.00000', '120.00000', '120000.00000', 0, 1, 1000, 0, 0, 1000, 1000, 0, 1000, 'disco_percent', '2021-09-14 05:22:22'),
(49, '956832', 49, 'Biscuit', '8964002528523', 'GLUCO Biscuit', '2801767379172', '2021-09-20', '2021-09-20', '10.00000', '10.00000', '0.00000', '0.00000', '10.00000', '10000.00000', 0, 1, 1000, 0, 0, 1000, 1000, 0, 1000, 'disco_percent', '2021-09-14 05:22:22'),
(50, '872108', 50, 'Biscuit', '8964002528547', 'GLUCO Biscuit', '654516171032', '2021-09-20', '2021-09-20', '115.00000', '100.00000', '0.00000', '0.00000', '100.00000', '100000.00000', 0, 1, 1000, 0, 0, 1000, 1000, 0, 1000, 'disco_percent', '2021-09-14 05:22:22'),
(51, '901701', 51, 'Biscuit', '8965310042510', 'Digwstive Biscuit', '1533945486758', '2021-09-20', '2021-09-20', '5.00000', '5.00000', '0.00000', '0.00000', '5.00000', '5000.00000', 0, 1, 1000, 0, 0, 1000, 1000, 0, 1000, 'disco_percent', '2021-09-14 05:22:22'),
(52, '60889', 52, 'Biscuit', '8964000473061', 'CHOCO Chip Biscuit', '2372845689803', '2021-09-20', '2021-09-20', '85.00000', '85.00000', '0.00000', '0.00000', '85.00000', '85000.00000', 0, 1, 1000, 0, 0, 1000, 1000, 0, 1000, 'disco_percent', '2021-09-14 05:22:22'),
(53, '517868', 53, 'Biscuit', '671866278928', 'Chip Choc Biscuit', '595725424522', '2021-09-20', '2021-09-20', '115.00000', '115.00000', '0.00000', '0.00000', '115.00000', '115000.00000', 0, 1, 1000, 0, 0, 1000, 1000, 0, 1000, 'disco_percent', '2021-09-14 05:22:22'),
(54, '806052', 54, 'Biscuit', '8964001381389', 'Shorties Biscuit', '2526756822312', '2021-09-20', '2021-09-20', '10.00000', '10.00000', '0.00000', '0.00000', '10.00000', '10000.00000', 0, 1, 1000, 0, 0, 1000, 1000, 0, 1000, 'disco_percent', '2021-09-14 05:22:22'),
(55, '651868', 55, 'Biscuit', '8964001381327', 'Shorties Biscuit', '846607940439', '2021-09-20', '2021-09-20', '10.00000', '10.00000', '0.00000', '0.00000', '10.00000', '10000.00000', 0, 1, 1000, 0, 0, 1000, 1000, 0, 1000, 'disco_percent', '2021-09-14 05:22:22'),
(56, '3392', 56, 'Biscuit', '8964000685518', 'Choco Licious Biscuit', '3319436004373', '2021-09-20', '2021-09-20', '115.00000', '115.00000', '0.00000', '0.00000', '115.00000', '115000.00000', 0, 1, 1000, 0, 0, 1000, 1000, 0, 1000, 'disco_percent', '2021-09-14 05:22:22'),
(57, '236572', 57, 'Biscuit', '8964000681411', 'Chocolate Biscuit', '724022969657', '2021-09-20', '2021-09-20', '17.00000', '17.00000', '0.00000', '0.00000', '17.00000', '17000.00000', 0, 1, 1000, 0, 0, 1000, 1000, 0, 1000, 'disco_percent', '2021-09-14 05:22:22'),
(58, '334886', 58, 'Biscuit', '8964002526529', 'CHOCO LICIOUS Biscuit', '328473604280', '2021-09-20', '2021-09-20', '115.00000', '100.00000', '0.00000', '0.00000', '100.00000', '100000.00000', 0, 1, 1000, 0, 0, 1000, 1000, 0, 1000, 'disco_percent', '2021-09-14 05:22:22'),
(59, '389381', 59, 'Biscuit', '8964001188810', 'WHISTAL Biscuit', '2803632548207', '2021-09-20', '2021-09-20', '10.00000', '10.00000', '0.00000', '0.00000', '10.00000', '10000.00000', 0, 1, 1000, 0, 0, 1000, 1000, 0, 1000, 'disco_percent', '2021-09-14 05:22:22'),
(60, '598314', 60, 'Biscuit', '8964001188629', 'WHISTAL Biscuit BUTTER', '3032742030639', '2021-09-20', '2021-09-20', '115.00000', '115.00000', '0.00000', '0.00000', '115.00000', '115000.00000', 0, 1, 1000, 0, 0, 1000, 1000, 0, 1000, 'disco_percent', '2021-09-14 05:22:22'),
(61, '754964', 61, 'Biscuit', '870572001619', 'CHOCOLATE Biscuit', '86145944353', '2021-09-20', '2021-09-20', '115.00000', '115.00000', '0.00000', '0.00000', '115.00000', '115000.00000', 0, 1, 1000, 0, 0, 1000, 1000, 0, 1000, 'disco_percent', '2021-09-14 05:22:22'),
(62, '122566', 62, 'Biscuit', '870572001718', 'Chocolatto Biscuit', '1332503732293', '2021-09-20', '2021-09-20', '115.00000', '115.00000', '0.00000', '0.00000', '115.00000', '115000.00000', 0, 1, 1000, 0, 0, 1000, 1000, 0, 1000, 'disco_percent', '2021-09-14 05:22:22'),
(63, '786347', 63, 'Biscuit', '8964000685488', 'Choco Licious Biscuit', '3070747597520', '2021-09-20', '2021-09-20', '5.00000', '5.00000', '0.00000', '0.00000', '5.00000', '5000.00000', 0, 1, 1000, 0, 0, 1000, 1000, 0, 1000, 'disco_percent', '2021-09-14 05:22:22'),
(64, '962681', 64, 'Biscuit', '8961003582004', 'Wheatable Biscuit', '1356226893164', '2021-09-20', '2021-09-20', '180.00000', '145.00000', '0.00000', '0.00000', '145.00000', '145000.00000', 0, 1, 1000, 0, 0, 1000, 1000, 0, 1000, 'disco_percent', '2021-09-14 05:22:22'),
(65, '359881', 65, 'Biscuit', '8961003654138', 'OREO Biscuit', '902225109037', '2021-09-20', '2021-09-20', '10.00000', '10.00000', '0.00000', '0.00000', '10.00000', '10000.00000', 0, 1, 1000, 0, 0, 1000, 1000, 0, 1000, 'disco_percent', '2021-09-14 05:22:22'),
(66, '93080', 66, 'Biscuit', '8964000681060', 'Sooper Biscuit', '442444968139', '2021-09-20', '2021-09-20', '115.00000', '115.00000', '0.00000', '0.00000', '115.00000', '115000.00000', 0, 1, 1000, 0, 0, 1000, 1000, 0, 1000, 'disco_percent', '2021-09-14 05:22:22'),
(67, '297781', 67, 'Biscuit', '8961003041020', 'Zeera Plus Biscuit', '2838882949364', '2021-09-20', '2021-09-20', '5.00000', '5.00000', '0.00000', '0.00000', '5.00000', '5000.00000', 0, 1, 1000, 0, 0, 1000, 1000, 0, 1000, 'disco_percent', '2021-09-14 05:22:22'),
(68, '121686', 68, 'Biscuit', '8964000685495', 'CHOCOLATE Biscuit', '2867079944847', '2021-09-20', '2021-09-20', '115.00000', '115.00000', '0.00000', '0.00000', '115.00000', '115000.00000', 0, 1, 1000, 0, 0, 1000, 1000, 0, 1000, 'disco_percent', '2021-09-14 05:22:22'),
(69, '377657', 69, 'Biscuit', '8964002487073', 'RITE Biscuit', '2485417645256', '2021-09-20', '2021-09-20', '100.00000', '95.00000', '0.00000', '0.00000', '95.00000', '95000.00000', 0, 1, 1000, 0, 0, 1000, 1000, 0, 1000, 'disco_percent', '2021-09-14 05:22:22'),
(70, '198078', 70, 'Biscuit', '870572009080', 'RITE Biscuit', '492515160851', '2021-09-20', '2021-09-20', '115.00000', '100.00000', '0.00000', '0.00000', '100.00000', '100000.00000', 0, 1, 1000, 0, 0, 1000, 1000, 0, 1000, 'disco_percent', '2021-09-14 05:22:22'),
(71, '19623', 71, 'Biscuit', '8964000784457', 'Gold Biscuit', '1672989637597', '2021-09-20', '2021-09-20', '85.00000', '85.00000', '0.00000', '0.00000', '85.00000', '85000.00000', 0, 1, 1000, 0, 0, 1000, 1000, 0, 1000, 'disco_percent', '2021-09-14 05:22:22'),
(72, '172224', 72, 'Biscuit', '8964002526628', 'Saltish Biscuit', '220736141212', '2021-09-20', '2021-09-20', '115.00000', '115.00000', '0.00000', '0.00000', '115.00000', '115000.00000', 0, 1, 1000, 0, 0, 1000, 1000, 0, 1000, 'disco_percent', '2021-09-14 05:22:22'),
(73, '714273', 73, 'Biscuit', '8964000682500', 'Party Biscuit', '2751378562381', '2021-09-20', '2021-09-20', '10.00000', '10.00000', '0.00000', '0.00000', '10.00000', '10000.00000', 0, 1, 1000, 0, 0, 1000, 1000, 0, 1000, 'disco_percent', '2021-09-14 05:22:22'),
(74, '710026', 74, 'Biscuit', '870572009622', 'Rite Biscuit', '3094684490712', '2021-09-20', '2021-09-20', '115.00000', '115.00000', '0.00000', '0.00000', '115.00000', '115000.00000', 0, 1, 1000, 0, 0, 1000, 1000, 0, 1000, 'disco_percent', '2021-09-14 05:22:22'),
(75, '320064', 75, 'Biscuit', '870572009615', 'Rite Biscuit', '552620202197', '2021-09-20', '2021-09-20', '10.00000', '10.00000', '0.00000', '0.00000', '10.00000', '10000.00000', 0, 1, 1000, 0, 0, 1000, 1000, 0, 1000, 'disco_percent', '2021-09-14 05:22:22'),
(76, '138588', 76, 'Biscuit', '8964002526123', 'peanut pista Biscuit', '145714307961', '2021-09-20', '2021-09-20', '20.00000', '15.00000', '0.00000', '0.00000', '15.00000', '15000.00000', 0, 1, 1000, 0, 0, 1000, 1000, 0, 1000, 'disco_percent', '2021-09-14 05:22:22'),
(77, '651273', 77, 'Biscuit', '8964001188940', 'Wheatable Biscuit Zeera', '2404044368991', '2021-09-20', '2021-09-20', '10.00000', '10.00000', '0.00000', '0.00000', '10.00000', '10000.00000', 0, 1, 1000, 0, 0, 1000, 1000, 0, 1000, 'disco_percent', '2021-09-14 05:22:22'),
(78, '15818', 78, 'Biscuit', '8964001188155', 'Whistle Biscuit', '1583079023520', '2021-09-20', '2021-09-20', '5.00000', '5.00000', '0.00000', '0.00000', '5.00000', '5000.00000', 0, 1, 1000, 0, 0, 1000, 1000, 0, 1000, 'disco_percent', '2021-09-14 05:22:22'),
(79, '43798', 79, 'Biscuit', 'b100', 'milky bred', '703262113069', '2021-09-20', '2021-09-20', '100.00000', '100.00000', '0.00000', '0.00000', '100.00000', '100000.00000', 0, 1, 1000, 0, 0, 1000, 1000, 0, 1000, 'disco_percent', '2021-09-14 05:22:22'),
(80, '827602', 80, 'Biscuit', '8961003654114', 'OREO Biscuit', '2100406930565', '2021-09-20', '2021-09-20', '10.00000', '10.00000', '0.00000', '0.00000', '10.00000', '10000.00000', 0, 1, 1000, 0, 0, 1000, 1000, 0, 1000, 'disco_percent', '2021-09-14 05:22:22'),
(81, '174594', 81, 'Biscuit', '8961003514159', 'PRINCE CHO JAM Biscuit', '1725581749398', '2021-09-20', '2021-09-20', '145.00000', '100.00000', '0.00000', '0.00000', '100.00000', '100000.00000', 0, 1, 1000, 0, 0, 1000, 1000, 0, 1000, 'disco_percent', '2021-09-14 05:22:22'),
(82, '802552', 82, 'Biscuit', '8964002528004', 'SOOPER Biscuit', '2326688057737', '2021-09-20', '2021-09-20', '5.00000', '5.00000', '0.00000', '0.00000', '5.00000', '5000.00000', 0, 1, 1000, 0, 0, 1000, 1000, 0, 1000, 'disco_percent', '2021-09-14 05:22:22'),
(83, '407504', 83, 'Biscuit', '8964001436775', 'Chai Wala Biscuit', '3123361809605', '2021-09-20', '2021-09-20', '115.00000', '115.00000', '0.00000', '0.00000', '115.00000', '115000.00000', 0, 1, 1000, 0, 0, 1000, 1000, 0, 1000, 'disco_percent', '2021-09-14 05:22:22'),
(84, '785564', 84, 'Biscuit', '8964000682067', 'Gluco Biscuit', '1970078310591', '2021-09-20', '2021-09-20', '115.00000', '115.00000', '0.00000', '0.00000', '115.00000', '115000.00000', 0, 1, 1000, 0, 0, 1000, 1000, 0, 1000, 'disco_percent', '2021-09-14 05:22:22'),
(85, '117693', 85, 'Biscuit', '8964002528028', 'Sooper Biscuit', '480306226587', '2021-09-20', '2021-09-20', '10.00000', '10.00000', '0.00000', '0.00000', '10.00000', '10000.00000', 0, 1, 1000, 0, 0, 1000, 1000, 0, 1000, 'disco_percent', '2021-09-14 05:22:22'),
(86, '656441', 86, 'Biscuit', '8961003031526', 'TIGER Biscuit', '3157962970272', '2021-09-20', '2021-09-20', '115.00000', '115.00000', '0.00000', '0.00000', '115.00000', '115000.00000', 0, 1, 1000, 0, 0, 1000, 1000, 0, 1000, 'disco_percent', '2021-09-14 05:22:22'),
(87, '97836', 87, 'Biscuit', '8964002528516', 'Gluco Biscuit', '1015562940714', '2021-09-20', '2021-09-20', '115.00000', '115.00000', '0.00000', '0.00000', '115.00000', '115000.00000', 0, 1, 1000, 0, 0, 1000, 1000, 0, 1000, 'disco_percent', '2021-09-14 05:22:22'),
(88, '195438', 88, 'Biscuit', '8964002526147', 'PEANUT PISTA Biscuit', '2270592561865', '2021-09-20', '2021-09-20', '115.00000', '100.00000', '0.00000', '0.00000', '100.00000', '100000.00000', 0, 1, 1000, 0, 0, 1000, 1000, 0, 1000, 'disco_percent', '2021-09-14 05:22:22'),
(89, '838650', 89, 'Biscuit', '671866277921', 'chip choc Biscuit', '1639607422960', '2021-09-20', '2021-09-20', '10.00000', '8.00000', '0.00000', '0.00000', '8.00000', '8000.00000', 0, 1, 1000, 0, 0, 1000, 1000, 0, 1000, 'disco_percent', '2021-09-14 05:22:22'),
(90, '263001', 90, 'Biscuit', '8964002528370', 'Rio Biscuit', '1386259531652', '2021-09-20', '2021-09-20', '20.00000', '20.00000', '0.00000', '0.00000', '20.00000', '20000.00000', 0, 1, 1000, 0, 0, 1000, 1000, 0, 1000, 'disco_percent', '2021-09-14 05:22:22'),
(91, '711074', 91, 'Biscuit', '8964000938010', 'CAFE Biscuit', '2012475491824', '2021-09-20', '2021-09-20', '10.00000', '10.00000', '0.00000', '0.00000', '10.00000', '10000.00000', 0, 1, 1000, 0, 0, 1000, 1000, 0, 1000, 'disco_percent', '2021-09-14 05:22:22'),
(92, '948088', 92, 'Biscuit', 'b070', 'Biscuitiks Bakery', '2570265633275', '2021-09-20', '2021-09-20', '70.00000', '70.00000', '0.00000', '0.00000', '70.00000', '70000.00000', 0, 1, 1000, 0, 0, 1000, 1000, 0, 1000, 'disco_percent', '2021-09-14 05:22:22'),
(93, '775930', 93, 'Biscuit', '8964002526659', 'Saltish Biscuit', '147235126683', '2021-09-20', '2021-09-20', '115.00000', '115.00000', '0.00000', '0.00000', '115.00000', '115000.00000', 0, 1, 1000, 0, 0, 1000, 1000, 0, 1000, 'disco_percent', '2021-09-14 05:22:22'),
(94, '934396', 94, 'Biscuit', '8964002528011', 'Sooper Biscuit', '3025378836032', '2021-09-20', '2021-09-20', '115.00000', '115.00000', '0.00000', '0.00000', '115.00000', '115000.00000', 0, 1, 1000, 0, 0, 1000, 1000, 0, 1000, 'disco_percent', '2021-09-14 05:22:22'),
(95, '25543', 95, 'Biscuit', '8964002527380', 'Sooper Biscuit', '1351855569226', '2021-09-20', '2021-09-20', '20.00000', '20.00000', '0.00000', '0.00000', '20.00000', '20000.00000', 0, 1, 1000, 0, 0, 1000, 1000, 0, 1000, 'disco_percent', '2021-09-14 05:22:22'),
(96, '473724', 96, 'Biscuit', '8961003522215', 'TUC Biscuit', '1016474773813', '2021-09-20', '2021-09-20', '115.00000', '115.00000', '0.00000', '0.00000', '115.00000', '115000.00000', 0, 1, 1000, 0, 0, 1000, 1000, 0, 1000, 'disco_percent', '2021-09-14 05:22:22'),
(97, '717386', 97, 'Biscuit', '8964002487578', 'Rite Biscuit', '1026807263829', '2021-09-20', '2021-09-20', '10.00000', '10.00000', '0.00000', '0.00000', '10.00000', '10000.00000', 0, 1, 1000, 0, 0, 1000, 1000, 0, 1000, 'disco_percent', '2021-09-14 05:22:22'),
(98, '71275', 98, 'Biscuit', '8965310041216', 'Digestive Biscuit', '2084612100154', '2021-09-20', '2021-09-20', '115.00000', '105.00000', '0.00000', '0.00000', '105.00000', '105000.00000', 0, 1, 1000, 0, 0, 1000, 1000, 0, 1000, 'disco_percent', '2021-09-14 05:22:22');
```

Comment: Don't include external links please...there is no reason why you can't list a suitable sample of your table data here. https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting if you need assistance with presentation. Questions which don't include all necessary info _within_ the question can be closed as off-topic.

Comment: You are right #ADyson but I included external links just to add my sample data.

Comment: Well that isn't acceptable, as I've explained. Add the sample data into your question please. See [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), point 1. The reason for this is that external links can change their content, or become inacessible over time. This then leaves your question in a state where future readers cannot fully understand it, making it useless. Since the purpose of Stackoverflow is to keep a repository of questions for everyone to benefit from, it's important that each question is self-contained as much as possible.

Comment: Its good #ADyson but how can I share more than 8000 MySQL records in my question ?

Comment: You can try an [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)

Comment: Please recall that I mentioned "a sample". We just need a [mre] of your issue, not every single thing associated with it. So a good spread of data relevant to the question is really all we need. Using a reduced dataset would also be a good test for you anyway, then you can see if the query is always slow, or if it depends somewhat on the quantity of data involved. A SQLFiddle is another external resource, but the links to each individual run are immutable, and it also gives us a way to run the code and see the schema properly, so that's also a good way to share with us.

Comment: #RiggsFolly
I am getting this error from sqlfiddle --> "Request content too large (>8000)"

Comment: Again...you need to usea _suitably reduced sample_ of your data. P.S. You must use @ if you want to tag people in the comments, not #. Otherwise, if they aren't still on the page and haven't chosen to "follow" the question, they won't see your message. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work

Comment: Ok I'll take care and I assure you @ADyson that I will never ever change/replace/delete/remove the above linked files. Please help. Thanks

Comment: You cannot really make that promise though. Google may change how Drive works, or remove access for some other reason, or maybe you fall under a bus and your account is closed, or some other reason you close your account and forget this was there. We'll be ready to help when the question is in an acceptable format for this site. Again, remember we're not here primarily as a troubleshooting helpdesk. We're here to create a repository of useful questions for the future. _You_ aren't the primary audience for the answers! We'll answer if the question is useful, and is in a truly preservable state.

Comment: (Solving your specific problem here and now is just a useful side-effect of creating this knowledge base for all programmers to make use of.)

Comment: @ADyson thanks a lot and I agree with you. Now I am editing my question.

Comment: Case in point @ADyson, I click the first drive link and get *Access denied: You need access
Ask for access, or switch to an account with access. Learn more*. Excellent gloss on what's being done here on SO and to what end.

Comment: Thanks for the update, that's much better. Can we also have sample values provided for the `$pid` and all the other PHP variables mentioned in the query, so we can see what values you're using when you run it. Thanks.

Comment: PHP variables explanation:   `$invoID = round(microtime(true) * 1000); ` , `$image = "n/a";`, `$salePrice = 100;`, `$status = "Available";`, `$cid = 1;`, `$uid = 1;`, `$pid = **plz see heading of table `purchase_order` 3rd column `pid`**  and `$ttlQinTempSale = its ordered qty it may be 1, 5, 89, 55 or any of your choice.`

Comment: Put that in the question too please, not the comments :-)

Comment: @ADyson I have updated the question and PHP variables are added.

Comment: hello @Strawberry as you helped me in  **How to SELECT and INSERT until ordered quantity is completed using nested query in MySQL**. I am unable to work with this solution on heavy data i.e. more than 5000 or more rows. its too slow please help and solve my problem. thanks

Comment: @vartec can you speedup my MySQL query plz ? I am newbie. When I run this query it takes much of time and being newbie i'm unable to resolve this issue.